# Why height of the list view is Full size?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, scroll

I want the list view to appear below the text view.
However, the text view is not visible and only the list view is displayed in full size. How do I fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="채팅"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because in the `ListView` you are using `android:layout_height="match_parent`.

You can do it in many ways, for example you can use the
**`android:layout_weight`** attribute. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view.

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
 
       <TextView
         ../>

       <ListView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should set layout_height = "wrap_content" in listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```